# On playing the Agricola Bielefeld minor improvement called Bielefeld Playing Cards, does it include animals?

Tags: agricola

We are playing with the Agricola Bielefeld card deck.  When playing the card called "Bielefeld Playing Cards", it says whenever you use an accumulation space, place all items on this card until you have accumulated 4 like items.  Then you can move the items to your playing board.  We are wondering if that would include animals... specifically cattle, since there aren't enough moves (with other players taking cattle) to ever get 4 cattle accumulated on the card.  Is this calculated into the points of the card since the card comes with 5 points on the card?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the chances of getting any cows on your farm are going to be limited.

There is [a nice post about the deck](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1153000/first-thoughts-bielefeld-deck) that includes a discussion of this card.

You are getting a lot of points in exchange for a lot of extra management of resources, so that is all factored in.  You have to decide if it is worthwhile and it probably depends on what other cards you might have that could assist.